# Fix touchpad behavior on Apple TV remote after wiping with alcohol?

Tags: appletv, remote-control

[image]

I wiped down my Apple TV remote for the [Apple TV 4K (5th generation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV#5th_generation_(4K)) ( a.k.a. [*Siri Remote*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Remote#Fourth-Generation_Apple_TV_and_the_Siri_Remote)) using 70 percent isopropyl alcohol as seemingly recommended by Apple on [this Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204172). Now the touch-sensitive surface on the remote is wonky, responding to my finger in all the wrong ways. The alcohol has dried, but the problem continues.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the Apple TV device to fix this problem. The catch is: How to restart the device without the remote working properly?

I suppose you could just pull the power plug on the device. But no need.

## Read menu items to Siri

You can drive the operation of the Apple TV by using Siri voice commands. Verbally read to Siri the menu items displayed on screen to restart the Apple TV: `Settings > System > Restart`.

1. Press the Menu or home button to return to list of app icons.
2. Tell Siri to open *Settings*.
3. Tell Siri “System”.
4. Tell Siri “Restart”.

After restart, your remote will function properly. This fix has worked for me several times.

Alternatively, according to [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201836) you can also restart the Apple TV this way:

> Hold down the Apple TV app/Home Home button and Menu buttons. Let go when the light on your device flashes.

[image]